# comparing to columns looking for similarity

Tags: c#, database, svn

I've got a program that is looking at what files have changed in each SVN commit, which will also highlight the area that has changed. I'm passing that data which has been retrieved from SVN and places it into a table in a SQL server database. What I'd like to do is compare the paths to see what area has been effected. I've already got a table which has a path that shows what area has been effected.

Example:

SVN:

```
branches/Projects/Enhancements2015Q1/WMDB/WMDB.cs
```

this is the path that has been found by the code

Compare table

```
branches/Projects/Enhancements2015Q1/GEM4/Utilities/Utilities.csproj = Utilities
branches/Projects/Enhancements2015Q1/WMDB/WMDB.cs = WMDB
trunk/src/GEM 4/GEM4/UI/Forms/AutoRenderOptionsForm.cs = UI
```

So what I'd like to find is that the path found in SVN has changed the WMDB.

Comment: Do you want to do this in the database, i.e. using SQL?

Comment: Yeah I'm using sql server